# How can I query mongodb collection for an array nested in an array of a document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection containing structurally similar documents as illustrated below-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("mongoid"),
    "type" : "chemical",
    "sourceId" : "27553452120",
    "array1" : [
        {
            "cid" : "1235689",
            "outcome" : "test",
            "relation" : "=",
            "array2" : [
                {
                    "name" : "test1"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "test2"
                },
                {
                    "value" : 1.628,
                    "name" : "test3"
                },
                {
                    "value" : 1.63,
                    "name" : "test4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query this collection for a case, where `array1.array2.length > 1`

I tried following sample query on mongo shell:

```
db.collection.find({"array1.array2":{$exists:true},$where:"this.array1.array2.length>1"}).limit(1).pretty()
```

but it *fails* stating

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "TypeError: this.array1.array2 is undefined :\n@:1:15\n",
    "code" : 139,
    "codeName" : "JSInterpreterFailure"
}
```

How can this query be achieved?

Comment: `db.collection.find( { $where: "this.array1.array2.length > 1" } );`

Comment: Hi @UsmanRana, I think I might have confused you because of the typo  initially in the question where I was accessing `array1.array1.length>1`. I have fixed it now to `array1.array2.length>1` and I have tried your suggested solution already and it does not work for me

Comment: hello @vishal. Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
db.test.aggregate(
{
$match:{"array1.array2": {$nin:[null,[]]}}
}
).pretty();
```

Comment: Thank you, but how I can make it a check on length of array rather than putting in negative constraints because lets say if I need to `array2` length > `some number (not necessarily 1)`, how can I do it?

Comment: try $size operator

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.collection.find({"array1.array2":{$exists: true, $ne : []}  })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned into above question please try executing following aggregate query as a solution.

```
db.collection.aggregate(

        // Pipeline
        [
            // Stage 1
            {
                $match: {
                    array1: {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            array2: {
                                $exists: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            // Stage 2
            {
                $project: {
                    array2size: {
                        $size: {
                            $arrayElemAt: ['$array1.array2', 0]
                        }
                    },
                    array1: 1
                }
            },

            // Stage 3
            {
                $match: {
                    'array2size': {
                        $gt: 0
                    }
                }
            },

        ]



    );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this way:

```
db.test.find({"array1.array2.1":{$exists:1}})
```

This is more flexible, it allow you to query for any length not only 1.

Last ".1" it is zero based array index. So if index 1 exists it means array has at least 2 elements. You can search for < N by changing $exists to 0. If no index 3 in array it means array has less then 4 elements.

If you need to search for exact size you can use $size operator

```
db.test.find({"array1.array2":{$size:5}})
```